# Getting error while giving command az aks get-credentials in Azure CLI

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-cli, azure-acr

I was getting below following error when giving this command. Can you please help me on this.

> az aks get-credentials --resource-group myResourceGroup --name
> myAKSCluster (ControlPlaneNotFound) Could not find control plane with
> ID 635910d0c727170001c75ea0. Code: ControlPlaneNotFound Message: Could
> not find control plane with ID 635910d0c727170001c75ea0.

I have installed Kubectl and minikube and config file also set in my local path under users/.kube/config but still i am getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Azure Cloud Shell. You won't encounter this problem  It's much easier and user friendly.

Comment: Getting error both Azure cloud shell in command prompt and as well as in Azure cloud shell.

Comment: I guess there is something wrong with the cluster because it can't reach the control node. Please create a new cluster and see if the problem persists.